# Is "there" an adverb or an exclamation in "so there!"?

Tags: idioms, adverbs, exclamatives

I often here people say:

> So there!

For defiance of something. My question is:

"so there" is an idiom, but in this context, having "there" used after "so".

Is "there" an adverb here? Or an exclamation?

Comment: According to Oxford Languages, it's an exclamation.

Comment: @KateBunting Mind writing an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oxford Languages calls **there** in this context an exclamation.

*Used to focus attention on something.
"There, I told you she wouldn't mind!"*

**So there** doesn't really have a logical meaning.

Comment: Nice answer! Perfect, feel free to vote up the question too :)